# Difference between std::size() vs sizeof() when determining array size

Tags: c++, sizeof

Consider

```
int array[5]{};
std::cout << std::size(array) << std::endl;
```

This will give me the result of 5.

```
int array[5]{};
std::cout << sizeof(array) << std::endl;
```

This will give me the result of 20.

Why is that? What is the difference on size and sizeof?

Comment: I'm curious about this too, since `std::size` is `constexpr` in modern C++, it makes the impression to supersede `sizeof`. When should we still use `sizeof` instead `std::size`? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: @303: They're two different tools that ask two different questions. If you're uncertain of which to use, that is either because you don't understand the difference between those questions or you aren't sure which question you're trying to ask.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yeah, it has been a while since I've used `sizeof` and a quick search wouldn't have hurt. Not sure what I was asking exactly. *"Move along, nothing to see here"* :D

Answer (score 8):

- `std::size` returns the number of array elements.
- `sizeof` is an operator that returns the number of bytes an object occupies in memory.

In your case, an `int` takes 4 byres, so `sizeof` returns a value 4 times larger than `std::size` does.

References:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size

---

There is an old trick to compute the number of array elements using `sizeof`:

```cpp
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
size_t arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

but this should *never* be used in modern C++ instead of `std::size`.