# Is std::size and sizeof same for a char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

If I use `std::size` and `sizeof()` for a char array, it gives the same value, so are those same for char array? I think these 2 work differently for different types, but are they same for char?

Comment: Show us how you used them.

Comment: how do I post a image here ?

Comment: Why do you need post an image? First read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Post your C++ program source code as text, never images/screenshots. Also please post a link to a working Godbolt example too.

Comment: Note `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`. So yes, both `sizeof` and `std::size` will give the same result here. See [Are there machines, where sizeof(char) != 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1-or-at-least-char-bit-8) and [Difference between std::size() vs sizeof() when determining array size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68158839/difference-between-stdsize-vs-sizeof-when-determining-array-size)

Comment: For C++, prefer C++ arrays (`std::array`) over C-style arrays.  For dynamic sizing, use `std::vector`.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`  *by definition* in the standard.  `std::size()` applied to an array is the number of elements in an array.  `sizeof` applied to an array will give the number of elements multiplied by the size of an element.   So, yes, the results (for an array of `char`) will be equivalent.    The mechanism by which the results are calculated typically differ (`std::size()` would not normally be explicitly implemented using `sizeof`).

Comment: An aside:    you might get a shock if you apply `sizeof` or `std::size()` to a raw string literal.   For example, `sizeof("AB")`  and `std::size("AB")` will both give a result numerically equal to `3`, not `2`.

Answer (score 2):

`.size()` returns the number of elements, whereas `sizeof()` returns the number of bytes. For a character array, each element is one byte, which explains why the number is the same

Comment: neither of the two is a member function. Character arrays dont have member functions. Why did you put a `.` in front ?

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the `.` before `sizeof()`. I believe c++ arrays of characters do have a `.size()` method however.

Comment: @MartinCook yes `std::array<char,N>` has a `size` method, but I am not sure of `sizeof(std::array<char,N>)` is guaranteed to be `N`.

Comment: @MartinCook   In C++, a (C-style) array does not have a `.size()` method.   A `std::array` does, but that is a `class`/`struct` that wraps an array.   In any event, the OP asked about `std::size()` which is not a member function of anything (it accepts the object or array it acts on as a (reference) argument).

Answer (score 0):

It's kindof sortof the case in thios particular example, but you shouldn't care. Observe:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    {
        char test[3];
        std::cout << "std::size(char[]): " << std::size(test) << '\n';
        std::cout << "sizeof(char[]): " << sizeof(test) << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    {
        int test[3];
        std::cout << "std::size(int[]): " << std::size(test) << '\n';
        std::cout << "sizeof(int[]): " << sizeof(test) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ -std=c++20 Test.cpp && ./a.out
std::size(char[]): 3
sizeof(char[]): 3

std::size(int[]): 3
sizeof(int[]): 12
```

`sizeof()` simply gives you the storage size of an object; this is something you'd need to allocate memory via `malloc`, for example.

`std::size()` gives you the number of items inside -- which is a very different thing, and more likely what you want. Although using C-style arrays comes with its own pitfalls anyway -- so that's also something you might not want to do.

Comment: 2 people have already answered , but I want to teach myself how to use Stack overflow , so that I dont make these mistakes henceforth . so here 's the code of what I tried .#include<iostream> int main(){char message5[]{'a','b','9','\0'};
std::cout << " message 5:" << message5 <<std::endl;

char message6[]{'a','b','69','\0'};
std::cout << " message 6:" << message6 <<std::endl;   }

Comment: @Harsh *how to use Stack overflow*: dont post code in comments ;) It is not readable. You can post an answer as answer or a follow up question as new question

Comment: In this case, I think the code is meant to be part of the question, not an attempt at an answer. I think in this case you could edit the question to add the code in, as this is what some of the comments were requesting.